# Nextjs (app) behind nginx reversed proxy results in permanent redirect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, next.js

I have problems in understanding the difference between the behavior of my Next.js (13.2.4) app locally and when deployed on my server running behind an niginx reversed proxy.

I have an nextjs app (using app router) with the following structure

```
/app
 - page.tsx
 - /overviewPage
    - page.tsx
```

When working locally in dev mode (`npm run dev`) I see the content of app/page.tsx on localhost:3000 and the content of app/overview/page.tsx on localhost:3000/overviewPage. Also this router pushing from page.tsx to overviewPage.tsx is working fine:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

// ...

// /app/page.tsx component
<CardActions>
    <Button size="small">Trading</Button>
    <Button size="small"onClick={() => { router.push("/overviewPage") }}>
    Historical Data</Button>
</CardActions>
```

As far as I understand the mappgings are:

1. app/page.tsx --> localhost:3000
2. app/overviewPage/page.tsx --> localhost:3000/overviewPage

When I run this app on my server on a docker mapped to the port 8001 of the host with a reversed proxy (nginx) that has locations configured like:

```
        location /_next/static {
                add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, immutable";
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/_next/static;
        }

        location /my/frontend {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

I **am able reach the content** of app/page.tsx via https://myserver.de/my/frontend.

So I would expect the same mapping behavior like local:

1. app/page.tsx --> https://myserver.de/my/frontend
2. app/overviewPage/page.tsx --> https://myserver.de/my/frontend/overviewPage*

But **I cannot reach the** overviewPage/page.tsx content via https://myserver.de/my/frontend/overviewPage. Also the router.push function seems to ignore the path segment of the frontend location and tries to call **https://myserver.de/overviewPage** which of course cannot be found.

When I curl this url, I get an HTTP 308:

```
curl -I https://myserver.de/my/frontend/overviewPage
HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 18 May 2023 06:15:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Location: /overviewPage
Refresh: 0;url=/overviewPage
```

access.log of nginx showing the redirect

```
77.20.122.199 - - [18/May/2023:06:23:00 +0200] "GET /my/frontend/overviewPage HTTP/1.1" 308 13 "-" "curl/7.87.0"
```

Further investigations showed the following behavior, which I do not understand as well:

When changing the path parameter for the `router.push` function to "/my/frontend/overviewPage" like:

```
// ...

// /app/page.tsx component
<CardActions>
    <Button size="small">Trading</Button>
    <Button size="small"onClick={() => { router.push("/my/frontend/overviewPage") }}>
    Historical Data</Button>
</CardActions>
```

it gets correctly resolved **locally** to localhost:3000/my/frontend/overviewPage (where nothing is found because locally there is no "/my/frontend/" location) there is a 404 page and no redirect to anywhere.

But on the server behind the reversed proxy this changed path parameter still tries to connect to https://myserver.de/overviewPage completely ignoring the "/my/frontend/" path segment.

Can someone explain this behavior and help me to find out how to get the expected mapping and working router on my server in the same way it works locally?

Comment: take a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath - as you are hosting app with basePath `/my/frontend`

Comment: @VladVladov this is exactly what I was searching for!. After clearing the cache of my browser (308 redirect was cached) I was able to reach my site also on the server. Thanks!